# Insert Blank value in DB2 for different data types

Tags: sql, db2, default

I have a table in DB2 with more than 150 columns of different data types including CHARACTER, DECIMAL, DATE, TIMESTAMP and VARCHAR.

I am creating an insert script for only one record where I need the first column to be populated by a default value and all remaining columns should be Blank irrespective of the data type.

For e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ... COL150)
VALUES ('hello','','','','' ... '')
```

COL1 is CHARACTER, COL2 can be TIMESTAMP, COL3 can be VARCHAR, COL4 can be VARCHAR. Can I use '' for all data types?

Comment: NULL and "blank" (empty string) are different things (although some other databases think they're not). Which do you want to insert?

Comment: blank should be fine for my use.

Comment: An empty string can only be used for character columns by definition.

Comment: just let the column to allow null and don't insert anything

Comment: can I just do this? INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ... COL150) VALUES ('hello',,,,,,,)

Comment: this `INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ... COL150) VALUES ('hello','','','','' ... '')` can be this INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1) VALUES ('hello')

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Let me try this and see if it works.

Comment: just create a function to insert the value  you want to insert in the column you wish to insert something...

Comment: Side note - a table with that many columns, of which a significant percentage are null, smells suspicious.  Depending on a few things, it may be more appropriate to break it up into smaller tables with fewer columns.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question well, but let me give it a better explanation than the one that I did in my comment.

Every time I have to insert something in my database I use, well my boss force me `lol`, to create functions.  In my `tables` most of the `col` allows `NULL` values.  So, this is an example (not perfect by the way):

```
function insertMajor($application_id, $major,$type, $conn){
//insert
$query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Applicant_Majors] "
        . "([application_id],"
        . "[program],"
        . "[type])"
        . "VALUES('$application_id','$major','$type')";

//connection
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

if ($stmt === false) {//start if
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }//end if

}
```

My `Applicant_Majors` table has more columns such as `name, date_of_declaration` etc, but does columns can be `null` or the user can leave that question in blank.

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do.

PS: I use `SQLserver 2008` my code can be different from yours

Comment: Why my answer have -2? If you love to follow Stackoverflow rules, at least provide some feedback before give it -1 -_- ...In this way, at least I will learn something new...don't you think so?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *Can I use '' for all data types?*

You don't have to. To insert the default value for a column use the keyword `default`:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
values ('hello', default, default, default);
```

This works regardless of the data type of the column.

Note that this won't work with columns defined as `NOT NULL` that do not have a non-null default value.